# How to give pre-selected tab and selected tabs a different background colour?

Tags: html, css, tabs

The page I am working on shows four tabs. I have two questions:

Question 1: When viewing page with Explorer, the selected tab (via CSS focus) shows a black background. However, when viewing the page with Edge, this does not seem to work. What do I need to change?

Question 2: Initially (with Explorer) the pre-selected tab (which is the first tab) does not show this black background. This black background only appears after clicking on one of the tabs but not after reloading the page. What changes do I need to have the pre-selected tab show the black background already immediately after page reload?

Please find the related code below

```
<style>
#tab1, #tab2, #tab3, #tab4 {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  background: #B00098;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

#tab1:hover, #tab2:hover, #tab3:hover, #tab4:hover {
  background: #E800C9;
}

#tab1:focus, #tab2:focus, #tab3:focus, #tab4:focus {
  background: #333333;
}

#tab1Content, #tab2Content, #tab3Content, #tab4Content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #B00098;
}

#tab1Content {
 display: block; 
}

#tab2Content, #tab3Content, #tab4Content {
 display: none; 
}

#tab2Content, #tab3Content, #tab4Content {
 display: none; 
}

.tops {
   vertical-align: top;
}

.text {
   text-align: justify;
   padding-right: 10px;
   width: 80%
}


img {
   padding-right: 5px;
   margin-top: -20px;
}


</style>



<script>
function selectTab(tabIndex) {
  //Hide All Tabs
  document.getElementById('tab1Content').style.display="none";
  document.getElementById('tab2Content').style.display="none";
  document.getElementById('tab3Content').style.display="none";
  document.getElementById('tab4Content').style.display="none";

  //Show the Selected Tab
  document.getElementById('tab' + tabIndex + 'Content').style.display="block";  
}

</script>





<div id="tab1" onClick="JavaScript:selectTab(1);">Boek 1</div>
<div id="tab2" onClick="JavaScript:selectTab(2);">Boek 2</div>
<div id="tab3" onClick="JavaScript:selectTab(3);">Boek 3</div>
<div id="tab4" onClick="JavaScript:selectTab(4);">Boek 4</div>

<br/>

<div id="tab1Content">
<table><tr><td class="text">
<b>Identiteit – Paul Verhaeghe</b><br>
Maatschappelijke veranderingen hebben gezorgd voor een veranderd ik-gevoel. Paul Verhaeghe onderzoekt de effecten van dertig jaar neoliberalisme, vrijemarktwerking, privatisering en de relatie tussen de maakbare samenleving en onze identiteit. Wie wij zijn wordt zoals altijd bepaald door de context waarin wij leven. Die context bepaalt op dit moment: Wie geen succes heeft zal ziek zijn.<br><br>

De dwang tot succes en geluk blijkt een keerzijde te hebben: het leidt tot verlies aan zelfbesef, tot desoriëntatie en vertwijfeling. De mens is eenzamer dan ooit. De liefde is moeilijk te bereiken en betekenisvol leven is diepgaand problematisch geworden. Vanuit zijn klinische ervaring als psychotherapeut laat Verhaeghe zien hoezeer de veranderde maatschappij doorwerkt in de hedendaagse individuele psychische problemen. Mensen komen met andere psychische klachten bij de psychiater dan voorheen.<br><br>

<b>Over de auteur</b><br>
Paul Verhaeghe (geb. 5 november 1955) is van opleiding klinisch psycholoog, van vorming psychoanalyticus. Zijn eerste doctoraat (1985) handelde over hysterie, zijn tweede (1992) over psychodiagnostiek. Hij werkt als gewoon hoogleraar aan de universiteit van Gent. Sedert 2000 gaat zijn belangstelling vooral naar de invloed van maatschappelijke veranderingen op psychologische en psychiatrische moeilijkheden. 
</td>
<td class="tops">
<img src="http://www.alumnei.nl/images/boekenactie_2017/boek_1.jpg" style="float: left; width: 120%; ">
</td></table>
</div>

<div id="tab2Content">
<table><tr><td class="text">
<b>Get your guts, je instinct als kompas – Hilde Bolt</b><br>
Iemand met Guts is een persoon met lef, met ballen. Maar heeft lef te maken met de darmen ('gut' = 'darm'), met onze buik? Een heleboel. Ons buikgebied bevat veel meer wijsheid dan we denken. Guts heeft een dubbele betekenis: de signalen uit het buikgebied zijn het instrument, het kompas van waaruit je kunt leven. En Guts is de kracht die je nodig hebt om hiernaar te handelen. Het leven kan mooi, maar ook vol risico's en soms wreed zijn. We kunnen niet altijd kiezen wat onze weg kruist. Toch is het vaak mogelijk om lichter, speelser, creatiever en eenvoudiger met het leven om te gaan.<br><br>

Get your Guts is een wake-up call, een herinnering aan je eigen oorsprong. De wijsheid van je lichaam, je buikgebied geeft je de mogelijkheid om oeroude instinctieve en verborgen kennis weer tot leven te brengen. Get your Guts is een boek voor mensen die zelf guts willen ontwikkelen, maar ook een boek dat iedere therapeut, coach of hulpverlener gelezen moet hebben.
<br><br>
<b>Over de auteur</b><br>
Hilde Bolt werkt als zelfstandig gevestigd coach, counselor, trainer en psychotherapeut. Ze heeft zich bijgeschoold in oosterse en westerse vormen van lichaamsgericht werken. Tijdens de trainingen creëert ze een veilige, creativiteit bevorderende sfeer waarin veel ‘op maat’ geëxperimenteerd kan worden zodat een ieder op een eigen manier het optimale rendement uit de training kan halen.
</td>
<td class="tops">
<img src="http://www.alumnei.nl/images/boekenactie_2017/boek_2.jpg" style="float: left; width: 120%; ">
</td></table>
</div>

<div id="tab3Content">
<table><tr><td class="text">
<b>Zin kun je maken - Ilse Vooren en Merlijn Koch</b><br>
Vanaf nu is zingeving begrijpelijk en hanteerbaar. Zin kun je maken benadert zingeving als een vermogen, waarbinnen vaardigheden en competenties te ontwikkelen zijn. We hebben meer ruimte dan ooit om stil te staan bij de betekenis van onszelf en ons bestaan. Zingeving speelt in onze diepste lagen en vragen en werkt door in het alledaagse leven. Wanneer en hoe ervaar je zin? Dit boek maakt helder hoe zingevingsprocessen werken en wat de functie van zingeving is.<br><br>
Zingeving hanteerbaar maken is belangrijk om richting te geven aan leven en werk. Voor coaches, leidinggevenden en andere professionals is praktische kennis van zingeving tegenwoordig essentieel. Het gesprek kunnen voeren op het niveau van betekenis is onderdeel van het nieuwe organiseren, leidinggeven en de zelfsturing van professionals.
Dit boek geeft concrete handvatten om processen van zingeving te begeleiden, individueel en in organisaties. Je ontdekt hoe je kunt bijdragen aan ervaringen van zin in alle verschijningsvormen, zoals motivatie, betrokkenheid, voldoening, (eigen)waarde en betekenis.<br><br>
<b>Over de auteurs</b><br>
Ilse Vooren en Merlijn Koch zijn beiden humanisticus. Ilse is oprichter van Food for Flow en gespecialiseerd in zingeving, energie en performance. Merlijn is coach en trainer bij de landelijke coachorganisatie Resilians, met expertise in het vergroten van vitaliteit en veerkracht.
</td>
<td class="tops">
<img src="http://www.alumnei.nl/images/boekenactie_2017/boek_3.jpg" style="float: left; width: 120%; ">
</td></table>
</div>


<div id="tab4Content">
<table><tr><td class="text">
<b>Mentaliserend Coachen – Peter Bleumer en René Meijer</b><br>
Mentaliseren is het vermogen tot zelfreflectie en inleving, beide noodzakelijk om goed te functioneren op het werk en privé. Sommige mensen kunnen niet goed mentaliseren, en veel mensen die dit vermogen wel hebben, verliezen het als ze stress ervaren of emotioneel zijn.<br><br>

Voor effectieve coaching en training is zelfreflectie van de deelnemers essentieel. Wat nu te doen als juist in dat gebrek aan mentaliserend vermogen het probleem schuilt? Dit praktische boek laat zien hoe mensen kunnen leren beter te mentaliseren. Het bevat concrete handvatten voor coaches, trainers en leidinggevenden voor het bevorderen hiervan.
<br><br>
<b>Over de auteurs</b><br>
Ilse Vooren en Merlijn Koch zijn beiden humanisticus. Ilse is oprichter van Food for Flow en gespecialiseerd in zingeving, energie en performance. Merlijn is coach en trainer bij de landelijke coachorganisatie Resilians, met expertise in het vergroten van vitaliteit en veerkracht.
</td>
<td class="tops">
<img src="http://www.alumnei.nl/images/boekenactie_2017/boek_4.jpg" style="float: left; width: 120%; ">
</td></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the second question first, using the `:focus` selector requires the item to be clicked, but you can set it to be focused when the window loads with javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("tab1").focus();
};
```

As for the edge/explorer issue, I am not able to recreate it because both browsers are failing to change the background color to `#333`, as you are trying to do.

To resolve both, I would suggest using classes instead of `:focus` in your CSS and JS.

**CSS:**

```
#tab1.selected, #tab2.selected, #tab3.selected, #tab4.selected {
  background: #333333;
}
```

**JS:**

```
document.getElementById('tab1').className = "";
document.getElementById('tab2').className = "";
document.getElementById('tab3').className = "";
document.getElementById('tab4').className = "";

document.getElementById('tab' + tabIndex).className = "selected"
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="selected" id="tab1" onClick="JavaScript:selectTab(1);">Boek 1</div>
<div id="tab2" onClick="JavaScript:selectTab(2);">Boek 2</div>
<div id="tab3" onClick="JavaScript:selectTab(3);">Boek 3</div>
<div id="tab4" onClick="JavaScript:selectTab(4);">Boek 4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to mtr.web, I managed to solve this issue. I have integrated his/her suggestions in the code.

Please find below the complete working code!

```
<style>
#tab1, #tab2, #tab3, #tab4 {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  background: #B00098;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

#tab1:hover, #tab2:hover, #tab3:hover, #tab4:hover {
  background: #E800C9;
}

#tab1.selected, #tab2.selected, #tab3.selected, #tab4.selected {
  background: #333333;
}

#tab1Content, #tab2Content, #tab3Content, #tab4Content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #B00098;
}

#tab1Content {
 display: block; 
}

#tab2Content, #tab3Content, #tab4Content {
 display: none; 
}

#tab2Content, #tab3Content, #tab4Content {
 display: none; 
}

.tops {
   vertical-align: top;
}

.text {
   text-align: justify;
   padding-right: 10px;
   width: 80%
}

img {
   padding-right: 5px;
   margin-top: -20px;
}
</style>

<script>
function selectTab(tabIndex) {
document.getElementById('tab1').className = "";
document.getElementById('tab2').className = "";
document.getElementById('tab3').className = "";
document.getElementById('tab4').className = "";
document.getElementById('tab' + tabIndex).className = "selected"

//Hide All Tabs
document.getElementById('tab1Content').style.display="none";
document.getElementById('tab2Content').style.display="none";
document.getElementById('tab3Content').style.display="none";
document.getElementById('tab4Content').style.display="none";
//Show the Selected Tab
document.getElementById('tab' + tabIndex + 'Content').style.display="block";  
}
</script>

<div class="selected" id="tab1" onClick="JavaScript:selectTab(1);">Boek 1</div>
<div id="tab2" onClick="JavaScript:selectTab(2);">Boek 2</div>
<div id="tab3" onClick="JavaScript:selectTab(3);">Boek 3</div>
<div id="tab4" onClick="JavaScript:selectTab(4);">Boek 4</div>
<br/>

<div id="tab1Content">
<table><tr><td class="text">
<b>Identiteit – Paul Verhaeghe</b><br>
Maatschappelijke veranderingen hebben gezorgd voor een veranderd ik-gevoel. Paul Verhaeghe onderzoekt de effecten van dertig jaar neoliberalisme, vrijemarktwerking, privatisering en de relatie tussen de maakbare samenleving en onze identiteit. Wie wij zijn wordt zoals altijd bepaald door de context waarin wij leven. Die context bepaalt op dit moment: Wie geen succes heeft zal ziek zijn.<br><br>
De dwang tot succes en geluk blijkt een keerzijde te hebben: het leidt tot verlies aan zelfbesef, tot desoriëntatie en vertwijfeling. De mens is eenzamer dan ooit. De liefde is moeilijk te bereiken en betekenisvol leven is diepgaand problematisch geworden. Vanuit zijn klinische ervaring als psychotherapeut laat Verhaeghe zien hoezeer de veranderde maatschappij doorwerkt in de hedendaagse individuele psychische problemen. Mensen komen met andere psychische klachten bij de psychiater dan voorheen.<br><br>
<b>Over de auteur</b><br>
Paul Verhaeghe (geb. 5 november 1955) is van opleiding klinisch psycholoog, van vorming psychoanalyticus. Zijn eerste doctoraat (1985) handelde over hysterie, zijn tweede (1992) over psychodiagnostiek. Hij werkt als gewoon hoogleraar aan de universiteit van Gent. Sedert 2000 gaat zijn belangstelling vooral naar de invloed van maatschappelijke veranderingen op psychologische en psychiatrische moeilijkheden. 
</td>
<td class="tops">
<img src="http://www.alumnei.nl/images/boekenactie_2017/boek_1.jpg" style="float: left; width: 120%; ">
</td></table>
</div>

<div id="tab2Content">
<table><tr><td class="text">
<b>Get your guts, je instinct als kompas – Hilde Bolt</b><br>
Iemand met Guts is een persoon met lef, met ballen. Maar heeft lef te maken met de darmen ('gut' = 'darm'), met onze buik? Een heleboel. Ons buikgebied bevat veel meer wijsheid dan we denken. Guts heeft een dubbele betekenis: de signalen uit het buikgebied zijn het instrument, het kompas van waaruit je kunt leven. En Guts is de kracht die je nodig hebt om hiernaar te handelen. Het leven kan mooi, maar ook vol risico's en soms wreed zijn. We kunnen niet altijd kiezen wat onze weg kruist. Toch is het vaak mogelijk om lichter, speelser, creatiever en eenvoudiger met het leven om te gaan.<br><br>
Get your Guts is een wake-up call, een herinnering aan je eigen oorsprong. De wijsheid van je lichaam, je buikgebied geeft je de mogelijkheid om oeroude instinctieve en verborgen kennis weer tot leven te brengen. Get your Guts is een boek voor mensen die zelf guts willen ontwikkelen, maar ook een boek dat iedere therapeut, coach of hulpverlener gelezen moet hebben.
<br><br>
<b>Over de auteur</b><br>
Hilde Bolt werkt als zelfstandig gevestigd coach, counselor, trainer en psychotherapeut. Ze heeft zich bijgeschoold in oosterse en westerse vormen van lichaamsgericht werken. Tijdens de trainingen creëert ze een veilige, creativiteit bevorderende sfeer waarin veel ‘op maat’ geëxperimenteerd kan worden zodat een ieder op een eigen manier het optimale rendement uit de training kan halen.
</td>
<td class="tops">
<img src="http://www.alumnei.nl/images/boekenactie_2017/boek_2.jpg" style="float: left; width: 120%; ">
</td></table>
</div>

<div id="tab3Content">
<table><tr><td class="text">
<b>Zin kun je maken - Ilse Vooren en Merlijn Koch</b><br>
Vanaf nu is zingeving begrijpelijk en hanteerbaar. Zin kun je maken benadert zingeving als een vermogen, waarbinnen vaardigheden en competenties te ontwikkelen zijn. We hebben meer ruimte dan ooit om stil te staan bij de betekenis van onszelf en ons bestaan. Zingeving speelt in onze diepste lagen en vragen en werkt door in het alledaagse leven. Wanneer en hoe ervaar je zin? Dit boek maakt helder hoe zingevingsprocessen werken en wat de functie van zingeving is.<br><br>
Zingeving hanteerbaar maken is belangrijk om richting te geven aan leven en werk. Voor coaches, leidinggevenden en andere professionals is praktische kennis van zingeving tegenwoordig essentieel. Het gesprek kunnen voeren op het niveau van betekenis is onderdeel van het nieuwe organiseren, leidinggeven en de zelfsturing van professionals.
Dit boek geeft concrete handvatten om processen van zingeving te begeleiden, individueel en in organisaties. Je ontdekt hoe je kunt bijdragen aan ervaringen van zin in alle verschijningsvormen, zoals motivatie, betrokkenheid, voldoening, (eigen)waarde en betekenis.<br><br>
<b>Over de auteurs</b><br>
Ilse Vooren en Merlijn Koch zijn beiden humanisticus. Ilse is oprichter van Food for Flow en gespecialiseerd in zingeving, energie en performance. Merlijn is coach en trainer bij de landelijke coachorganisatie Resilians, met expertise in het vergroten van vitaliteit en veerkracht.
</td>
<td class="tops">
<img src="http://www.alumnei.nl/images/boekenactie_2017/boek_3.jpg" style="float: left; width: 120%; ">
</td></table>
</div>

<div id="tab4Content">
<table><tr><td class="text">
<b>Mentaliserend Coachen – Peter Bleumer en René Meijer</b><br>
Mentaliseren is het vermogen tot zelfreflectie en inleving, beide noodzakelijk om goed te functioneren op het werk en privé. Sommige mensen kunnen niet goed mentaliseren, en veel mensen die dit vermogen wel hebben, verliezen het als ze stress ervaren of emotioneel zijn.<br><br>
Voor effectieve coaching en training is zelfreflectie van de deelnemers essentieel. Wat nu te doen als juist in dat gebrek aan mentaliserend vermogen het probleem schuilt? Dit praktische boek laat zien hoe mensen kunnen leren beter te mentaliseren. Het bevat concrete handvatten voor coaches, trainers en leidinggevenden voor het bevorderen hiervan.
<br><br>
<b>Over de auteurs</b><br>
Ilse Vooren en Merlijn Koch zijn beiden humanisticus. Ilse is oprichter van Food for Flow en gespecialiseerd in zingeving, energie en performance. Merlijn is coach en trainer bij de landelijke coachorganisatie Resilians, met expertise in het vergroten van vitaliteit en veerkracht.
</td>
<td class="tops">
<img src="http://www.alumnei.nl/images/boekenactie_2017/boek_4.jpg" style="float: left; width: 120%; ">
</td></table>
</div>
```